# Сохранение положения ползунка у Switch

Tags: android, kotlin, switch

Вот есть у меня некий Switch, и он находится не на основном Activity (MainActivity), а на втором Activity (я его назвал SettingsActivity).
Следуя из названия, по нажатии некой кнопки открывается новое действие с меню настроек, где и находится мой Switch.
Допустим я нажал на Switch и изменил значение с false на true и нажал на кнопку применить, которая перенесёт меня обратно на основное действие.
В основном действии я опять открою настройки, но ползунок у Switch снова стоит на false.
Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы ползунок у Switch "сохранялся", когда я переключаюсь между действиями и выхожу из приложения?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: гуглите sharedpreferences. Также можно сохранять в файле, БД, на сервере и т д.